# Why can't Visual Studio collapse Javascript functions that include Razor syntax?

Tags: javascript, razor, visual-studio-2013

My .cshtml file in Visual Studio looks like this:

[image]

Notice how `createTabStrip` can collapse, but `createTeachersTab` cannot. Why is this?

EDIT: It seems to have something to do with the razor syntax. I took out all of the `@` signs and `createTeachersTab` was able to collapse.

Comment: Good question, I've noticed that VS doesn't quite have the collapsing figured out in js yet. It might work if you collapse the file and then open it again.

Comment: @asven No, unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: I think the better question might be, why do you need to use Razor syntax in a function definition? Things like URLs should be configuration, where you have one Razor view that basically spits out a JavaScript object literal.

Comment: @GregBurghardt How would I access said Razor view from a JS function?

Comment: You don't need to. The Razor view is just part of the regular page. It creates a JavaScript literal, which you can then reference from your function. I'm going to post an answer in a few minutes to show you what I mean.

Comment: Thx Lincoln,  Glad I found this.  See you when you get back ;).

Comment: This is pretty annoying though...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand on my comment.

You generally do not want to define functions in your Razor views. Instead, define them and import them from an external JavaScript file. If you need info from C# in JavaScript, you could create a global config object in JavaScript in a Razor partial, then render that partial.

**function_lib.js**

```
function createTeachersTab() {
    ...
        read: {
            url: config.teachers.newTabUrl
        }
    ...
}
```

**Views/Shared/_JavaScriptConfig.cshtml**

This would be rendered as a Partial in the `<head>` of the HTML document.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var config = {
        teachers: {
            newTabURL: '@Url.Action("Teachers", "Users")'
        }
    };
</script>
```

Then anywhere else in your JavaScript, you can reference these settings via the global `config` JavaScript variable.

```
config.teachers.newTabUrl
```

Edit: I also completely recognize that this does not solve the code collapsing problem in Visual Studio, which appears to be a parsing bug on their end. The real solution is "Don't define JavaScript functions in Razor views" as this is considered bad practice.

Comment: Thanks, this will really cut down on my View's file size (it's approaching 1000+ lines now).

Comment: Why is it considered a bad practice to define javascript functions in Razor Views?

Comment: @SotirisZegiannis: Putting JavaScript functions in Razor views means the browser cannot cache the code, and just adds to the bits sent across the network. There are always cases where you can break this rule, but my first instinct is to put them in their own file, unless I find a *really, really, really, really* good reason not to.

Comment: Hadn't thought of it. Thank you @GregBurghardt for your response.

Answer (score 4):

Also you can highlight the block and press ctrl + m, ctrl + h to collapse the block

Comment: this worked great. The collapsible button appeared after doing this once.